# Weird select.select() behavior in Python

Tags: python, select

I'm trying to read from stdin character by character with a Python script, using `select.select()` to be notified whenever something is available. I'm facing a behavior that I don't understand; it's probably best illustrated with an example. First of all, here is a sample select code:

```
import select
import sys

while True:
    r, w, e = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [])
    print "Read: %s" % sys.stdin.read(1)
```

Now here is a sample run of the script:

```
/tmp$ python test.py 
AAAA     # I type in a few chars then ENTER.
Read: A  # Only one char is detected :(
BBBB     # I type in more characters
Read: A  # Now all the previous characters are detected!?
Read: A
Read: A
Read:    # ('\n' is read which I want)

Read: B  # Wait, where are the other Bs?
CCCC     # I need to type more chars so that BBB is printed, and the first C.
```

As you can see above, if multiple characters are typed in `stdin`, only the first one is printed. Then, if more characters are added, all the remaining ones from the previous input are printed plus the first one of the new input.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the importance of `r, w, e` (are they needed?)

Comment: Not really. `sys.stdin.read` can be replaced with `r[0].read` but the problem remains the same.

Comment: What Python version are you on?

Comment: Python 2.7.9, but I've just checked that this also happens in Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select.select` is unaware of the buffering in a Python file object (such as `sys.stdin`). You can bypass the file object entirely, though this will interact strangely with attempts to read from `sys.stdin`:

```
import select
import os
import sys

while True:
    r, w, e = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [])
    print os.read(sys.stdin.fileno(), 1)
```

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks for figuring this out, I was pulling out my hair on this one.